# Do format-patch from the commits between a specific Tag and the last commit

Tags: git, format-patch

How do I do a format-patch from the commits between a specific tag and the last commit?

I need to do it using git commands and\or C# code.

Currently, I succeeded to get all the relevant commits by:

```
git log --pretty=oneline HEAD...tag
```

now I need to know how to do a format-patch just on them

Comment: what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched? please also read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git format-patch` receives the same range argument format as `git log`. You'd also probably want to add the `-o` argument to specify the output directory for thee patches:

```
git format-patch HEAD..tag -o /tmp/patches
```